# Jackson Array of Objects

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 3589954,
    "type": "e",
    "pos": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 3837014,
    "type": "p",
    "pos": 2
  }
]
```

and the following Java Class:

```
public class Business {

private int idBusiness;

private String type;

private int pos;

public Business(int idBusiness, String type, int pos) {
    this.idBusiness = idBusiness;
    this.type = type;
    this.pos = pos;
}

// getters & setters .........
}
```

and I am trying to read it as:

```
businessList = mapper.readValue(strBusinessIDArrayJSON, new TypeReference<List<Business>>(){});
```

I am not able to read the JSON - I get businessList = null after the call. What is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'm surprised you get `null` and not a bunch of exceptions.** (I'll assume you are swallowing the exceptions.)

You need a no-argument constructor, or you need to annotate the parameters in your current constructor with `@JsonProperty` with the name of the JSON element to which they should map. It might look like

```
public Business(@JsonProperty("id") int idBusiness, @JsonProperty("type") String type,@JsonProperty("pos") int pos) {
    this.setId(idBusiness);
    this.type = type;
    this.pos = pos;
}
```

Note that the JSON contains the property `id`, not `idBusiness`, so you need a `@JsonProperty("id")` over the field, getter, or setter (or rename the field and its getter/setter).

Comment: @AmarMond You're welcome. Were you swallowing the exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

You should name your property better:

```
private int id;
```

Alternatively you could use `@JsonProperty(value="id")` as annotation on your "idBusiness"